# How can I set amCharts stacked column style colors automatically

Tags: amcharts

I want to create a generic chart for stacked column charts. I will create an angularjs directive that contains a `<div id="chart"></div>` and my charts will be in it.

I am settings a dataProvider for amCharts but I need to set colors all of items. Does not generate colors automatically?

Comment: The colors are set automatically as you can see [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-column-chart/). By default it generates colors for each *graph*. If you're coloring individual segments in each category differently from the next, then you want [`fillColorsField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColorsField). That part isn't automatic and you need to specify the colors yourself in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please provide your data provider, and do you provide it at the time of initialization of chart or you are providing it dynamically?

Here is an example from amchart with data provider in initialization time.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sujittiwari/c5d2nugc/3/)

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
},
"dataProvider": [{
    "year": 2003,
    "europe": 2.5,
    "namerica": 2.5,
    "asia": 2.1,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.2,
    "africa": 0.1
}, {
    "year": 2004,
    "europe": 2.6,
    "namerica": 2.7,
    "asia": 2.2,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.3,
    "africa": 0.1
}, {
    "year": 2005,
    "europe": 2.8,
    "namerica": 2.9,
    "asia": 2.4,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.3,
    "africa": 0.1
}],
"valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0
}],
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Europe",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "europe"
}, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "North America",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "namerica"
}, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Asia-Pacific",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "asia"
}, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Latin America",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "lamerica"
}, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Middle-East",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "meast"
}, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Africa",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "africa"
}],
"categoryField": "year",
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
},
"export": {
    "enabled": true
 }});
```

Comment: jsfiddle example is 404 not found